# get all the links in a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get all the links in the page using `.each(function(){});` in JQuery

```
<div id="mm">
    <ul class="mg">
        <li id="nav_sports">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" class="atest">Sports</a>
            <div id="sports">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.dictionay.com">cricket</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="cont1">
                    <li style="color:#444444">
                        <b>Popular</b>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what i expected guys...thanks for ur replies

```
$("a").attr("clink","");
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#mm a").attr("clink","");
        $('#mm a').each(function(){
            var hrefl=$(this).attr('href');
            var clink=hrefl;
            $(this).attr('clink',clink);
            $(this).attr('href',"#");
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 19):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    //Do your work   
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the anchor tag as selector

```
$("a").each(....)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var links = [];
$('#mm a').each(function() {
   links.push( this.href ); 
   // output of links: ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.dictionay.com']
   // According to comment
   // if you need each link separately then
   // may try like

   var href = this.href;
   // now process with the href as you wish      
});
```

for all `a`s, change the selector `#mm a` to just `a`;

Answer (score 4):

If you want all the unique links on a page, borrowing from other answers on this page and [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self)
{
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
} 

function getAllLinks()
{
   var links = [];
   $("a").each(function ()
   {
      links.push(this.href);
   });

   return links.filter(onlyUnique);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `$('a')` this will return a collection of al the A elements on a page.

Then you can iterate over it with `$('a').each(function(index, value){})`